# inherit operator new from base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory-management

[This page](http://www.relisoft.com/book/tech/9new.html) (from C++ in action book) shows code:

```
class Link
{
    friend class FreeList;
public:
    Link (Link * pNext, int id)
    : _pNext (pNext), _id (id) {}

    Link *  Next () const { return _pNext; }
    int     Id () const { return _id; }
    // allocator
    void * operator new (size_t size)
    {
        assert (size == sizeof (Link));
        return _freeList.NewLink ();
    }
    void operator delete (void * mem)
    {
        if (mem)
            _freeList.Recycle (mem);
    }
    static void Purge () { _freeList.Purge (); }
private:
    static    FreeList _freeList;

    Link *  _pNext;
    int     _id;
};
```

And then say

> Class Link has a static member
>   _freeList which is used by the overloaded class-specific operators
>   new and delete. Notice the assertion
>   in operator new. It protects us from
>   somebody calling this particular
>   operator for a different class. How
>   could that happen? **Operators new and
>   delete are inherited. If a class
>   derived from Link didn't override
>   these operators, new called for the
>   derived class would return an object
>   of the wrong size (base-class size).**

Is this saying true? I think new will be called with right size of derived object. Why not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `new` expression will cause an allocation function (`operator new`) to be called with the correct size for the object being constructed. That's what the `size_t` parameter for `operator new` is for.

The particular implementation of `operator new` in the example, however, can only cope with uniform sized allocation requests. If a derived class didn't override `operator new` *this implementation* of `operator new` would be called with a size that it can't cope with (aka "wrong").

It is, in general, perfectly possible to write an `operator new` for a class that can handle allocation requests for derived classes.

Comment: @zaharpopov: Perhaps not an error, but a very misleading way of putting something.

Comment: what in this implementation make it not possible to allocate for derive clsses? how can it be written correctly?

Comment: @zaharpopv: `operator delete` just recycles memory blocks onto the free list regardless of size, `operator new` uses recyclyed blocks or `FreeList:::NewLink` which only uses `sizeof(Link)` blocks of memory. Why `FreeLink` doesn't actually use `::operator new` directly like the comment suggests it should, rather than `::new char[]`, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

if the derived class has no data members, then i think sizeof(derived) == sizeof(Link) and the assertion in op new in Link will not fail.

```
class derived : public Link {};

derived* d = new derived(); //should call Link's op new
```